# How is the comet facebook implementation for their Notifications feature

Tags: facebook, http, comet

How is the comet facebook implementation for their Notifications feature?

I'm crazy to know, I'm looking for something similar that wouldn't cost much from the web server...

Does anybody know or Anyone had experience with that?

thanks

Ed